# More than 4 players on PES

Tags: pc, pro-evolution-soccer-2011, pro-evolution-soccer-2012

Is there a way (perhaps by a patch) to add more than four players using joysticks on PES 2011 or 2012.

It's for PC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. While the PS3 supports up to 8 players, XBox360 allows only 4. Most games that are available on consoles and on PC use the XBox360 version, because it is very close to the PC architecture.

Street Fighter X Tekken has a similar [problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65705/is-it-possible-to-play-street-fighter-x-tekken-with-2-players-online-on-one-pc). On the PS3 version you can play online with a buddy on one console, but on Xbox and on PC you cannot.

I guess PES will not release such a patch. Perhaps the next generation Xbox will allow for more players.