# Is it possible to play Street Fighter X Tekken with 2 players online on one PC?

Tags: street-fighter-x-tekken

The XBox360 version allows only one player to play online, so if you want to play online  with your buddy (same team), you basically need 2 XBox360s each with a copy of the game.

Will the PC version be the same? Do I need 2 PCs with one copy each to play 2 player tag team online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Similar to the Xbox360 version, same system online co-op will **not** be available on the PC version.

This has been answered by Cacpom [here](http://www.capcom-unity.com/ask_capcom/go/thread/view/7371/29018899/Will_the_PC_version_of_Street_Fighter_X_Tekken_have_Local_Online_Co-op?pg=2)

Comment: I guess my best option to still play online with my friend is to bring my laptop. :(

Comment: Or play the PS3 version... If I answered your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to play multiplayer  on the PC version. You can use any two types of inputs to play. Two gamepads , one gamepad & keyboard, or even both of you use the same keyboard (not recommended for obvious reasons).

Comment: You need to add some more detail to this.  As it stands, it's basically a yes answer.